# MIPS random number generator syscall 40&41

Tags: mips, system-calls

```
# SEED
# 1 - load the generator ID
# 2 - seed the generator
# First Number
# 1 - Load the generator ID
# 2 - Bound the random number generator to less than or equal to 128
# 3 - Display the message
# 4 - Display first number
```

Im new to MIPS so was trying out this piece of code and im a little stuck. I'm trying to use syscall 40(set seed)&41(random int) any pointers or suggestions would help. Thanks

```
 .data
Message: .asciiz "\n The random number you generated was: "
genID:      .word 1
seed:    .word 1235
 .text
 .globl main

main:

#la $a0, genID
#lw $v0, seed

#la $a0, genID
li $v0, 41
li $a1, 128
syscall

li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use service #40 to set up the PRNG seed and then service #42 to get the next number from that PRNG within the bounds you desire:

```
.eqv genID 1  # PRNG id
 .data
Message: .asciiz "\n The random number you generated was: "
seed:    .word 1235
 .text
 .globl main

main:

li $a0, genID
lw $a1, seed
li $v0, 40
syscall

# li $a0, genID  # $a0 still has genID, 
li $v0, 42
li $a1, 129  # upper bound (not includes this number)
syscall  
move $t0, $a0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Message
syscall

move $a0, $t0
li $v0, 1
syscall  # print PRNG number

li $v0, 10
syscall  # terminate
```